# Compare to variable from other class

Tags: java, class, methods

I tried so hard but I couldn't get this to work. My method "guess" in class "Game" should compare the parameter "someInt" with the variable "x" from the class "Number". I would really appreciate any help, I have to get this done this evening. This is what I got, so far:

```
public class Number
{
private int x;

/**
 * Constructor for class Number.
 * This constructor assigns x to a new random 
 * number between 1 and 100
 */
public Number()
{
    // The following lines creates a random number 
    // between 1 and 100 and assigns it to x
    java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random();
    x = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
}

public int getNumber(){
    return x;
}
}
```

And my other class:

```
public class Game
{
private Number number;

/**
 * This constructor should initialize the filed number
 */
public Game() {
   Number number1 = new Number();
   number1.getNumber(x);

}

/**
 * This method takes a parameter "someInt" and 
 * compares it with the value stored in "this.number".
 * If "someInt" is less than the value stored in "this.number",
 * then the system should print "Your guess is too small" on the screen;
 * if "someInt" is larger than that value,
 * then the system should print "Your guess is too large" on the screen;
 * otherwise it should print "You win!".
 */
public void guess(int someInt) {
    if (someInt < x){
        System.out.println("Your guess is too small");
    }
    else if (someInt > x) {
        System.out.println("Your guess is too large");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("You win!");
    }    
}
}
```

Comment: replace `number1.getNumber(x);` with `int x = number1.getNumber();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modified version

```
public class Game
{
private Number number;

/**
 * This constructor should initialize the filled number
 */
public Game() {
   this.number = new Number();

}

/**
 * This method takes a parameter "someInt" and 
 * compares it with the value stored in "this.number".
 * If "someInt" is less than the value stored in "this.number",
 * then the system should print "Your guess is too small" on the screen;
 * if "someInt" is larger than that value,
 * then the system should print "Your guess is too large" on the screen;
 * otherwise it should print "You win!".
 */
public void guess(int someInt) {
    if (someInt < number.getNumber()){
        System.out.println("Your guess is too small");
    }
    else if (someInt > number.getNumber()) {
        System.out.println("Your guess is too large");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("You win!");
    }    
}
}
```

On the other hand, you shouldn't use classes with the same names as in `java.lang`, as `Number`. It's distracting, making your code hard-readable and bug-genic.

The problems were:

- `Number.getNumber()` does not take arguments, you provided one
- You created a local object `number1` while you should be operating on `number`.
- In `guess()`, you used `x`, instead, `Number.getNumber()` should be used.

I recommend renaming `Number` to something not causing name clashes with `java.lang.Number`.

Answer (score 0):

this here is wrong:

```
public Game() {
   Number number1 = new Number();
   number1.getNumber(x);

}
```

because `Number.getNumber()` takes no param and must return an int (it is a *GETTER*)...

maybe you meant to do:

```
public class Game {
    private int x;
    private Number number;

/**
 * This constructor should initialize the filed number
 */
public Game() {
   Number number1 = new Number();
   this.x = number1.getNumber();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have number1.getNumber(x); , but getNumber in your number class has no arguments.

In your getNumber method you have a return of x. You need to handle it in game like:

int numberToCompare; (declare below private Number number)

number1.getNumber(x); must be numberToCompare = number1.getNumber();

then you need to compare someint with numberToCompare.